# JQuery Change Background Color of 'Option' Element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm in a bit of a rut, i've searched high and low for a JQuery method to change the background color of an item in a drop-down menu (`<select><option>foo 1</option><option>foo 2</option></select>`) on hover. How am i supposed to do this?

Comment: It would be better if you elaborated by posting your failed attempt, you will get more appreciation and more responses.

Comment: @karim79 The question's pretty straightforward, in this case.

Comment: @DN, true, but it's good manners to post the failed attempt(s) so that hopefully we can answer the question, but also point out other problems that may cause future bugs, etc.

Comment: @DN - I disagree, I've managed to change option styles, but not in a cross-browser way. I was merely trying to encourage an illustrative question and hopefully learn from the responses. :)

Comment: Good points, both. I must be in some sort of 'wrong' rut today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>You can't generally visually affect `option` directly. You have to simulate the dropdown in order to style it.</del>

And I completely got that wrong. Apologies! Shouldn't have gone off my memory--you can do basic styling on select boxes. See here, though, for the ways it will vary from browser to browser: http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/form_controls/select/

That demo assigns style just to `select`, but you can do

```
option { background-color:#eeeeee; }
```

and even assign classes, etc. as noted by [Alan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394393/jquery-change-background-color-of-option-element/2394482#2394482). The discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182035/is-there-a-way-to-enhance-by-css-an-html-select-and-its-option-on-ie-6) point out some of the IE6 limitations--which you can see pretty well from the visual rundown the other link gave.

So I've been testing and googling for a bit now, and the good news for you is that current support for background-color/text color on options or whole selects is pretty good, but ultimately spotty the older the browser is. Optgroups are *still* troublesome. And anything complex is troublesome (which is probably why I recalled it as totally broken). For deeper styling issues, a slightly more up-to-date, but less comprehensive look can be found here: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/style-select-optgroup-options-css/

Comment: How would i go about simulating it?

Comment: http://www.brainfault.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-selectbox-replacement/ Check this article.

Comment: There are a few plugins--this is a nice-looking one I've considered using, but haven't yet: http://www.scottdarby.com/2009/05/jquery-plugin-stylish-select-unobstrusive-select-box-replacement/

Comment: @scopus That looks promising, but it's missing some fairly basic stuff you'd want, like keyboard entry (has up/down, but not letters to jump to the first match, for instance) and it looks he's ignoring IE6 for the moment, which could be an issue.

Comment: Cheers DN for the solution + a big thank you to scopus for the link :D
IE6 & keyboard up/down isn't a prioriety for me yet, but i will definitely be saving your link!
Thanks again guys :)

Comment: I stand corrected. Basic styling will work, as Alan says. I can't believe I forgot that. Answer left for the plugin linkage, and answer being edited, but please feel free to re-award the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the background color of `option` elements and the `select` element (not sure whether this works reliably cross browser). You apparently can't affect the style of the "hover" effect in the dropdown list, though. You certainly don't need JavaScript for this approach, however. Just define `background-color` for them or give them IDs if you need finer granularity.

If you want full control, currently the best approach is "faking it" by creating `div`s or `ul`s and `li`s with the apropriate styling and JavaScript event handling (i.e. hover, click, etc). The problem with this tends to be that there is no such a thing as an "unselect" event, so you have to cheat in order to figure whether the dropdown should be dismissed (I think most jQuery plugins and such that make this easier cheat by having an input element of some kind be "active" behind the scenes and dismissing the dropdown when it loses focus).

It's all about the smoke and mirrors. Just make it "look" like a dropdown, even if it doesn't actually look like one in the source code.